# 5 V and Ground Reverse direction

Tags: voltage

I have a circuit drawing like below image.
I need to replace a connector, but when I checked the connection is different compare to the original drawing. (New connection indicated by red color)

1) Original :-

- CN25 (pin3) 5 V --> CN 10 (pin 1)
- CN25 (pin1) GND --> CN 10 (pin 22)

2) New Connector :-

- CN25 (pin1) GND --> CN 10 (pin 1)
- CN25 (pin3) 5 V --> CN 10 (pin 22)

Is there any problem with new connection?

Appreciate in advance all the comments and answer

[image: New Connection]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Looks like the new connector is incompatible with existing board power connections. If you can manually fix the cable, fine, but either fix it or get the correct connector. As it is right now you would be shorting out power. Not Good.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any problem with new connection?

Yes. The polarity is reversed on the new cable. This could destroy the "board to control".